# CMake isn't able to include header file into my source file

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I'm learning CMake and got to the part where I learn how to include header files. The problem is that I get an error, saying that the header file has not been found.

I'm on Windows 10, by the way.

All I have as of right now is a `src` and `include` directories along with the `CMakeLists.txt` file. In source, I only have a single file and I also only have a single file in include.
This is my `main.cpp` file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "include/main.h"
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    sayHi("Joshua");
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my `CMakeLists.txt` file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
project(hello VERSION 1.0)
add_executable(hello ../src/main.cpp)
target_include_directories(hello PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SRC_DIR}/include)
```

**EDIT:** I fixed the source code so that I includes `main.h`, rather than `include/main.h`, but I still end up with the same error:

````
"C:\Users\HP\desktop\test\4\build\hello.sln" (destino padrão) (1) ->
"C:\Users\HP\desktop\test\4\build\hello.vcxproj.metaproj" (destino padrão) (3) ->
"C:\Users\HP\desktop\test\4\build\hello.vcxproj" (destino padrão) (4) ->
(ClCompile destino) ->
  C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test\4\src\main.cpp(3,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'main.h
': No such file or directory [C:\Users\HP\desktop\test\4\build\hello.vcxproj]

    0 Aviso(s)
    1 Erro(s)
    ```

What is going on?
````

Comment: What are the verbatim errors you see, when running your build??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ

"C:\Users\HP\desktop\test\4\build\hello.sln" (destino padrão) (1) ->
"C:\Users\HP\desktop\test\4\build\hello.vcxproj.metaproj" (destino padrão) (3) ->
"C:\Users\HP\desktop\test\4\build\hello.vcxproj" (destino padrão) (4) ->
(ClCompile destino) ->
  C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test\4\src\main.cpp(3,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'includ
e/main.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\HP\desktop\test\4\build\hello.vcxproj]

    0 Aviso(s)
    1 Erro(s)

Is what I get.

Comment: @badolsmito You have `include` twice. You have put it in your code and your makefile. You only need it once.

Comment: @badolsmito [Edit] your question to add additional information please!

Comment: @john I fixed the source code but I still end up with the same error.

Comment: `#include` simply concatenates every path in include directories with whatever is in `""` and tries to open such file. So, currently, it tries to open `./include/main.h` (with `.` being path to `main.cpp`, I guess it's `project_path/src/`) and then `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SRC_DIR}/include/include/main.h` (and then some system paths). Both files don't exist, so `#include` directive fails.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen but even after I made the fix, where it now includes "main.h" instead of "include/main.h", I get an error.

Comment: Your output doesn't look like CMake output, more like somehting Visual Studio solution would output? (not sure, never used VS myself). Are you sure that CMake is used to build your code?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yes, it is a Visual Studio solution.

Comment: I mean, Visual Studio has its own build system. If you press "compile" (or whatever the button is called), I guess by default it uses its own build system, not CMake (and therefore CMake is ignored). But I may be absolutely wrong about that, just shooting a guess.

Comment: You're going to need verbose build output so that you can see all include paths.  I have no idea how to enable that with visual studio, so you'll have to dig through menus.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen the way CMake works is to construct a build system for the compiler you are using. So in this case it has constructed a Visual Studio project (but wrongly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`, not `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SRC_DIR}`.

If you fix this then the compiler should see the correct include directory.

At the moment because the variable doesn't exist, the only directory it sees is `/include` which is not what you want.